# NULL comparison in scala udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, isnull

I have a spark dataframe with columns A, B, C, D all of type double. I need to add a new column 'ratio' which is to be calculated as below:

```
if(A IS NULL && B IS NULL)
  then 0
if(A IS NOT NULL && B IS NULL)
  then A/D
if(A IS NULL && B IS NOT NULL)
  then C/B
if(A IS NOT NULL && B IS NOT NULL)
  then A/B
```

How can this be done in scala as Double cant be compared with NULL?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do it.

The first is to define your udf's parameters to be java.lang.Double instead of Double

This would make writing the udf simple but it would probably be slow due to boxing and unboxing between the double primitive and the java util Double object.

A better way is to not use UDF at all. You can use dataframe semantics:

```
df.withColumn("newOne", when($"a".isNull && $"b".isNull, lit(0)).otherwise(when($"a".isNotNull && $"b".isNotNull, $"a"/$"d").otherwise(...))
```

Basically the with is the save as the if, the otherwise is the same as an else. $"a".isNull checks if the value of the column a is null and isNotNull checks if it is not null. lit(N) gives N to all elements and you can use $"a"/$"b" to calculate the ratio between the value in a and b columns